# I want to know if the two JavaScript snippets are the same or not

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I am new to  JavaScript and I want learn more about it.

For example:

```
a == true && alert("a is true");
```

Is this similar to:

```
if(a == true)
{
    alert("a is true");
}
```

If the above code is correct and if they both are equal, then I want to know all operators and conditions like this. Where can I find them?

Comment: can you please select correct answer from below; so as this will help others. :P

Comment: @Parag - please give OP some time .. this question was barely asked half an hour a go. Take your time, RG and only accept an answer if it really helped you.

Comment: @Marijn yes you are  right :) . I had put the comment since I thought the user is new to stackoverflow so just to inform him. :p

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer: **the result, which is the alert box, will be the same.**

Explanation:

Most languages are designed to evaluate the second expression only if the first one evaluated to `true`, in case of an `&&` expression.

This means that if `a` evaluates to `false`, `null`, `undefined`, an empty string, `0`, or `NaN`, `alert("a is true")` won't be evaluated, and you won't see the alert box.

JavaScript has values which can be "truthy" or "falsy", I suggest you read more about that here: http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript.

So, it depends on your definition of "same", the result, i.e. seeing or not seeing the alert box, is the same.

If you want to know more about different operators in JavaScript, and how they work, check out: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

Comment: It also won't evaluate the alert if `a` evaluates to `null` or `undefined`. You might want to clarify that in your answer.

Comment: OP asked about a == true && alert("a is true"); but you are explaining about a && alert("a is true"); Those are different and I do not think that it is clear for OP.

Comment: No, @SergeyS. Don't be *this* pedantic. After all, by coercion, `a && alert()` *is* the same as `a == true && alert()`.

Comment: @SergeyS, I don't see a reason for a downvote. Also, I am explaining what OP asked about. If a does eval to any of those things I listed, then a == true will eval to false.

Answer (score 7):

The only difference between the two is that this is an expression:

```
a == true && alert("a is true");
```

But this is a statement:

```
if (a == true) {
    alert('a is true');
}
```

The outcome of the expression depends on what `a == true` evaluates to.

```
false && alert('a is true'); // false (and alert box does not show up)
true && alert('a is true');  // undefined (after alert box is clicked away)
```

This works thanks to the "short circuit" behaviour of evaluating expressions; using `&&`, the first condition that's falsy will become the result of the expression without evaluating the rest.

Another operator that has similar kind of behaviour is the logical or `||`. Consider:

```
a || alert('a is false');
```

This shows the alert box if `a` evaluates to falsy.

```
false || alert('a is false'); // undefined (after alert box is clicked away)
true || alert('a is false');  // true (alert box does not show up)
```

Note that expressions with side effects like these are considered "clever" solutions; they may shorten your code, but the original intent is not always obvious.

That said, there are good uses of this as well, for instance:

```
a = a || 'default value';
```

This will assign a default value to `a` if it's falsy and the original value of `a` otherwise. You can see these expressions quite often and they're a powerful feature of the language.

Answer (score 3):

It is not Javascript special syntax - it is just a tricks to shorten code.

There is no magic. It is just a plain logic. Usually such tricks are used by code-minimizers to shorten code. This behavior is based on && and || operators important property - they do not evaluate second part of expression if result becomes known from first part (in opposite to & and | operators, which are always evaluate both parts of expression).

Usages explained:

```
a==true && alert("a is true");
```

If 'a' is false - javascript engine analyzes that the whole expression MUST be false too (because of meaning of '&&' (AND) logic operator) - and it omits second part of expression because no matter what it returns result it will not change result of whole expression. So it does not run 'alert'. In opposite if 'a' is true - than Javascript engine need to know the result of second part of expression and it runs 'alert'. Such behavior mimics usual 'if' statement.

```
a==false || alert("a is true");
```

This one is using 'OR' logic operator. If 'a' is false then there is no need to evaulate second part of expression and 'alert' is fired. If 'a' is true' then there is a chance that second part of expression will be 'true' and whole expression evaluates to 'true' - so javascript engine runs 'alert'.

Moreover those shortcuts can be shortened even more. Because there is no need to compare two boolean values: 'a' and 'true', because 'a' is already boolean value. It makes following:

```
a && alert("a is true");
```

Basically you do not need to use such things manually, just use normal 'if' statements - it will make your code readable. You can then use code-minimizers to shorten your code for production if necessary.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good examples, how `&&` works, in the other answers, so I'm not going to repeat them. Anyways...

When the expression is evaluated, it sends a return value as an outcome. In your particular case (1st example) the return value is not used anywhere and the result is the same with 2nd example. But if we'd use that return value, say in `if` condition, we might get a bit confusing results. Here's an example:

```
var a = true;
if (a == true && alert('a = true')) {
    alert('a really is true');
} else {
    alert('It seems, that a is not true');
}
```

This codesnippet will first alert "a = true", and the second alert will be "It seems, that a is not true". This is due to the return value of DOM native function `alert()`, which returns `undefined`, which makes the condition being falsy (`true && undefined === false`). Thus we can say, that your codesnippets are equal in that particular context, but they are not in some other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

They both do the same thing.  It comes down to how you prefer your code to look and most (I think) would agree that the 2nd version is best to read.

`If` statements stop execution when they come to a false (in the case of && operators), so the first statement says "if a is true, then if alert...", meaning that if a is true then the alert will be shown.

That is exactly the same outcome as the 2nd version.

Comment: "If statements stop execution when they come to a false..." This is only the case for `&&` expressions.

Comment: @Yannbane Correct - thanks for pointing out my faux pas - modified :)

Answer (score 0):

The two sets of code yield the same result but are not the same

For the first code set,

```
a == true && alert("a is true")
```

the [logical operator `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) is used.

While evaluating a statement with `&&`, `false && anything` is short-circuit evaluated to false.

So, in the first statement alert(1) is not called if `a` is false. The js compiler skips the `alert` statement.

If `a` is true, then alert(1) is executed because the condition is not short-circuited.

In the second set, the normal `if` condition is used. Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Answer (score -1):

this code do the same thing, check if a is true then call function alert, I guess I can say is same.

Comment: This is pretty imprecise answer.

Comment: good question, just have to write a lot of javascript and look at javascript frameworks, check others code ;) and have a litle flair ;) gl & hf

Comment: @RGA if you want to learn different coding styles, seek them out yourself :) I would advice you to look into both object oriented and functional style languages. Javascript lends itself well to functional style because functions are first class objects. The reason these two statements to the same, is that `&&` shortcuts if one of the operands is false (e.g. `a == true`) - hence the rest doesn't get evaluated (e.g. the `alert(...)` part).